# Android video restarted with orientation

Tags: android, video, orientation, reloading

How to **avoid reloading** of video with orientation change i.e force the video to resume from same.

i  have tried below but it fails

```
vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vplayer);
.......
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Position",vd.getCurrentPosition());
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    int position= savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
    vd.seekTo(position);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is stop your Activity to get re-created when orientation changes. You can do that by adding in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the `activity tag`

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```